# iOS App crash issue with upgrading to iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

When I try to optimize my existing iOS app to iOS7 app with recommended settings using XCode 5
the app is crashing and it shows following log

**Log :**

```
2013-09-20 19:21:56.794  -[UIStatusBarStyleRequest length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb562d0

2013-09-20 19:21:57.660  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIStatusBarStyleRequest length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xdb562d0'

*** First throw call stack:

(

0   CoreFoundation                      0x040e55e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x037f48b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x04182903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
3   CoreFoundation                      0x040d590b ___forwarding___ + 1019
4   CoreFoundation                      0x040d54ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   Foundation                          0x012318a2 -[NSDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 36
6   Application                             0x000a9b65 -[NSDictionary(Subscript) objectForKeyedSubscript:] + 85
7   UIKit                               0x01fe5fbc +[UIStatusBar _styleAttributesForRequest:] + 144
8   UIKit                               0x01fe619e -[UIStatusBar _styleAttributesForRequest:] + 43
9   UIKit                               0x01fe293a -[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animationParameters:] + 99
10  UIKit                               0x01fe27bf -[UIStatusBar requestStyle:animated:] + 101
11  UIKit                               0x01fe21be -[UIStatusBar forceUpdateStyleOverrides:] + 88
12  UIKit                               0x01fe6510 -[UIStatusBar _evaluateServerRegistration] + 278
13  UIKit                               0x01fe63f5 -[UIStatusBar didMoveToSuperview] + 33
14  UIKit                               0x01be71a6 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 472
15  UIKit                               0x01be6ef8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 260
16  UIKit                               0x01bf2031 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1847
17  UIKit                               0x01be5521 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
18  UIKit                               0x01fd9ed8 -[UIStatusBarWindow setStatusBar:] + 339
19  UIKit                               0x01b8be0e -[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:] + 203
20  UIKit                               0x01b88e34 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 436
21  UIKit                               0x01b9d42c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
22  UIKit                               0x01b9d999 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
23  UIKit                               0x01b8ac35 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
24  GraphicsServices                    0x048782eb _PurpleEventCallback + 776
25  GraphicsServices                    0x04877df6 PurpleEventCallback + 46
26  CoreFoundation                      0x04060dd5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
27  CoreFoundation                      0x04060b0b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
28  CoreFoundation                      0x0408b7ec __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
29  CoreFoundation                      0x0408ab33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
30  CoreFoundation                      0x0408a94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
31  UIKit                               0x01b886ed -[UIApplication _run] + 840
32  UIKit                               0x01b8a94b UIApplicationMain + 1225
33  Application                              0x0009333d main + 141
34  libdyld.dylib                       0x03cd9725 start + 0
```

)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I also searched the google for the above issue with the error message but i did not found anything regarding the issue.

Please help me to resolve the issue asap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code which make the app crash

Comment: Desymbolicate the log and show the code for `Application                             0x000a9b65 -[NSDictionary(Subscript) objectForKeyedSubscript:] + 85`

Comment: This is related (but the solution will be different for you): https://devforums.apple.com/message/886097#886097

Comment: Thanks trojanfoe. With your reference link, I solved my issue.